# Pip3 and python are not synchronized | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, numpy, pip

So my problem started when in Spyder I wanted to import library from python (wget). Even though module was clearly installed (through both pip and conda) Spyder couldn't see it.

I tried to resolve the issue.
Firstly I reinstalled python - still same issue.

Now I try to reinstall whole conda environment.
But even though I removed conda after uninstalling modules for example `numpy pip3 uninstall numpy`, then installing `pip3 install numpy` I still get Error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`

Honestly guys I have no clue now how can I resolve my issue and setup my python environment once again.

I'm running everything on macOS terminal.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently reinstalling conda helped me to solve the problem. 
The environment seems to be working fine.

For macOS I removed:

- `rm -rf ./anaconda3` from opt folder in users
- removed anaconda3 from PATH
- removed all anaconda3 dependencies

I leave the post, because maybe someone has the same issue.